# update get error in catch exception and the message is in the description

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I don't understand y i am getting this kind of error...below you can see the update sqlquery.

```
protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pID = Convert.ToString(Session["PatientId"]);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pID))
    {
        int patientID = Convert.ToInt32(pID);

        SqlConnection connew = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Upadate [dbo].[PatientDetails] set [title] = @pttit, [sex] = @ptgen, [lastname] = @ptlastnm, " +
                    " [birthday] = @ptbirth, [firstname] = @ptfirstnm, [middlename] = @ptmiddlenm, [remarkline] = @ptremarkln, [remarks] = @ptremark " +
                                                                        "where [PatientId] = '"+pID+"'", connew);



            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pttit", txtpttitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptgen", txtgender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptlastnm", txtptlastnm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptbirth", txtptbirthday.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptfirstnm", txtptfirstnm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptmiddlenm", txtptmiddlenm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptremarkln", txtptremarkline.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptremark", txtremarks.Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connew;

            if (connew.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connew.Open();
            }
            try
            {                        
                //rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error Occured: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                connew.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
}
```

When i debug the code...it goes into catch and show the error message : Incorrect syntax near '.'....can anybody have the idea where i am wrong....it would be great if anybody correct my code which will update the table in database.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use `stored procedure` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelt Update wrong...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Upadate [dbo].[PatientDetails] set [title] = @pttit, [sex] = @ptgen, [lastname] = @ptlastnm, " +
                 " [birthday] = @ptbirth, [firstname] = @ptfirstnm, [middlename] = @ptmiddlenm, [remarkline] = @ptremarkln, [remarks] = @ptremark " +
                                                                        "where [PatientId] = '"+pID+"'", connew);
```

Comment: What difference ? Can you tell me that difference ?

Comment: hmm ! okay keep it up

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a start `upadate` is not a SQL command.

Now you seem to have some understanding of the use of SQL Command Parameters. So why on earth have you abandoned the path of true righteousness and concatenated a parameter at the end?!

```
where [PatientId] = '"+pID+"'
```

Comment: @Pratik Don't do `where [PatientId] = '"+pID+"'`, do `where [PatientID] = @patientID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , add the pID in command parameter thet you call the cmd parm name in your query

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Update [dbo].[PatientDetails] set [title] = @pttit, [sex] =

 @ptgen, [lastname] = @ptlastnm,[birthday] = @ptbirth, [firstname] = @ptfirstnm, [middlename] = 

@ptmiddlenm, [remarkline] = @ptremarkln, [remarks] = @ptremark where [PatientId] = @pID", connew);



            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pttit", txtpttitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptgen", txtgender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptlastnm", txtptlastnm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptbirth", txtptbirthday.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptfirstnm", txtptfirstnm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptmiddlenm", txtptmiddlenm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptremarkln", txtptremarkline.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptremark", txtremarks.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID",pID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            string title = "niraj";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update [dbo].[PatientDetails] set title=@title", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```